# Soap UI vs Curl Response tIme Difference

Tags: curl, soapui

I have hosted a soap service built using spring in one of our data centers. When I test via SOAP UI , I get the response in 1 second or less. However when I run the same request via CURL , it takes more than 30 seconds to execute. I am running both the commands from same machine. What could be causing this difference?

```
curl  -H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" -H "SOAPAction:"  -d @request.xml <endpoint>
```

Comment: Can you write the `curl` command?

Comment: @randomir I updated the curl command

Comment: Maybe you should use `Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8`. But definitely you should define your `SOAPAction` header, because right now it's invalid -- `curl` doesn't send it at all.

Comment: Thanks @randomir. when I use application/xml , i see this error : {"timestamp":1511205140609,"validationMessages":[]}curl: (18) transfer closed with 273352 bytes remaining to read

Comment: When I use  --data-binary instead of -d , it seems to return fast

Comment: Well, I'm glad we worked this out. :)

Comment: Thank you! looks like -d strips new line etc whereas --data-binary sends the request as is. I saw it in another stackoverflow post. Please can you post your answer and I will accept and add bounty :) Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Cool, I'll write it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things to consider:

- the media type (`Content-Type` header field) for SOAP requests should be `application/soap+xml` (see [SOAP 1.2 specs, end of section 1.3](https://www.w3.org/TR/soap12-part1/#reltoxml)). If your encoding is UTF-8, then set `Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8`.
- your `SOAPAction` header field is left undefined, meaning `curl` is not sending that field at all. You can check this if you run `curl` with [`--trace-ascii /dev/stdout`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--trace-ascii) option.
- to send your XML (binary) payload as-is, you can use [`--data-binary`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-binary) option, instead of [`-d/--data`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-d). It will preserve newlines and carriage returns. For XML content that shouldn't make any difference, but that probably depends on strictness of parser and schema used.
- when debugging `curl` requests, it's useful to bounce the request off of echo sites like [httpbin](http://httpbin.org/), as well as enable full verbosity with `-vvv`, maybe even use `--trace*` to inspect the exact payload sent/received.

Applying those fixes, your `curl` command will look like:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8' \
     -H 'SOAPAction: Some-Action' \
     --data-binary @request.xml \
     <endpoint>
```

Comment: looks like I can only award bounty after 23 hrs. will do it tomorrow.